# How to extend this Lemma to three variables?

Tags: number-theory

**Lemma:** If $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers such that for any integer $a$ the following hold: $a^p\equiv a \pmod q$ and $a^q\equiv a \pmod p$. Then $a^{pq}\equiv a\pmod {pq}$.

I want to prove that $561|2^{561}-2$, but $561=3*11*17.$ So, I guess the above written Lemma is useless. I thought that this Lemma might work since it was useful in showing that $2^{340}\equiv 2\pmod{341}$, where $341=11*31.$

Comment: @Evariste: He wrote $2^{561} - 2$.

Comment: The kind of numbers you are looking for are [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)